# Detached DOM tree memory leak angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak problem in my application and was hoping you guys could help. After examining the problem, I have come to the conclusion that the it is caused by the following code:

I have a couple of html files where I use `ngFor` to create some html code for each object in an array:

```
<div class="patient-box level-1" *ngFor="let bed of beds">
  more html..
</div>
```

In the component, I have subscribed to an observable which emits a new array every now and then:

```
updateBeds(purge: boolean) {
  this._beds.next(this.bedsData);
}
```

This is what happens when I receive the new array:

```
this.patientService.beds.subscribe(updatedBeds => {
  this.beds = updatedBeds;
  this.sortBeds(this.sortProperty);
});
```

I think what's happening here is when I assign a new reference to the `beds` array, all html code in the `ngFor` is removed, and then new html code will be created for the objects in the updated array from the observable.

The problem is that html code that gets removed when the update arrives doesn't seem to be garbage collected. After taking multiple heap snapshots over some time, I see more and more detached DOM trees, and some of them keep increasing their retained size. I don't see any nodes highlighted yellow in the snapshots, but I have lots of red ones.

I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I have especially noticed a lot of red `HTMLInputElement` and `HTMLImageElement` nodes from this code inside the `ngFor`:

```
<p>
  <img draggable="false" [matTooltip]="translations?.Tooltip.O2" (click)="toggleO2(bed)" [src]="bed.additional_O2 ? medO2 : noO2">
</p>
<input class="jump-button" [matTooltip]="translations?.Tooltip.Jump2" type="image" src="../../assets/images/Jump_1-2.png" (click)="moveBed(bed, 2)">
```

I really don't know what to do at this point. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I was looking for the same info, noticing an increasing Detached DOM count, with no Yellow nodes associated with them. Clicking GC in DevTools doesn't have any effect. See open memory leak issues: https://github.com/angular/angular/labels/severity4%3A%20memleak